# How to get html of many class using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with JQuery.
My example:

```
<div id="one">XXX</div>
<div id="one">YYY</div>
<div id="one">ZZZ</div>

<script>
        a = $("body").find("#one").html();
        document.write(a);
</script>
```

This is only display XXX . But I want to display XXX, YYY and ZZZ. How? Tell me how to use **.find('#id').html()** for many elements with same Id in one page?

Comment: **ID must be unique.**

Comment: You don't have any *class* let alone many

Comment: But with two or mores ID? How to I solve my problem? :((

Answer (score 7):

Use `class` instead of `id`.

> ID should be unique across HTML page.

```
$(".one").each(function(index,val){
  document.write($(val).html());
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="one">XXX</div>
<div class="one">YYY</div>
<div class="one">ZZZ</div>
```

Comment: But how about with Id?

Comment: Downvoting for no reason. No explanation too. This happens a lot.

Comment: @Manwal downvoted because when you posted you did not mention anything about the id.

Comment: @Akki619 Your concern is correct. I couldn't be so fast in improving answer.

Comment: @Manwal wirte full answer then post ... how would I know you were thinking or about to write. As you corrected it now I am voting up.

Comment: But my problem only with Id. I am very sad :((((((

Comment: @TiteKubo what stopping you with using class?

Comment: Can't you change your `ID` to class @TiteKubo?

Comment: @Akki619 This is my homework! With only div id="one" :(

Comment: @TiteKubo this giver of this problem need to learn a lot about **HTML**.

Comment: Can you help me? Please :((((

Comment: @TiteKubo Jai has given the answer you need..The only question you need to ask who gave you this as homework. what is the significance of having same id's on a page for elements and for what purpose?

Answer (score 5):

This is not a good practice to have same ids for multiple elemetents and that makes a bad markup to work with js.

Although you can do this:

```js
var arr = $('div[id="one"]').map(function(){
    return this.textContent;
}).get();

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + arr + '</pre>'
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">XXX</div>
<div id="one">YYY</div>
<div id="one">ZZZ</div>
```

### Note:

Still i recommend not to use this code. This is just for demonstration that you can get it this way.

Better to change `id` attribute to `class` and use it.

```js
var arr = $('.one').map(function(){
    return this.textContent;
}).get();

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + arr + '</pre>'
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">XXX</div>
<div class="one">YYY</div>
<div class="one">ZZZ</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ID's should be unique. Change the Id's to classes and this should work.

```
$('.one').each(function(index, obj) {
    document.write($(this).html());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3wb5zdxo/1/

Comment: Bro! It's not the div id="one" :(

Answer (score 0):

Id for an element should be unique.

For Example

```
<div id="one">XXX</div>
<div id="two">YYY</div>
<div id="three">ZZZ</div>

<script>
        a = $("body").find("#two").html();            
        document.write(a);
</script>
```

Comment: :( Bro. I told you

<div id="one">XXX</div>
<div id="one">YYY</div>
<div id="one">ZZZ</div>

Answer (score 0):

Your markup isn't correct. You can have only **ONE** `id` in your code.

Change with this code instead :

```
<div class="one">XXX</div>
<div class="one">YYY</div>
<div class="one">ZZZ</div>
```

Then, according to your code, here is the JS to get the html of the `div`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('div').each(function(i,e) {
    console.log($(e).html());
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks bro. I will try now <3

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not have duplicate ids. You can rather use same class:

```
<div class="one">XXX</div>
<div class="one">YYY</div>
<div class="one">ZZZ</div>
```

and then use:

```
document.write($('.one').map(function(){return $(this).html()}).get().join(","));
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/621hj48f/)**

Comment: But with multi Id? Bro? :(((((

Answer (score 0):

it is not allowed to have several elements with the same id. id hast to be unique in the DOM. You can user class instead

```
<div class="one">XXX</div>
<div class="one">YYY</div>
<div class="one">ZZZ</div>
```

everyone else showed you how to do it with jQuery. I you don't want to use jQuery for some reason anymore you can do it  with javascript just like that:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('one');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    alert(elements[i].innerHTML);
}
```